# Typesetting tick marks on an axis so that the space occupied by the minus sign is ignored

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The error in the following code seems to be at the following options specified in the `axis` of the `pgfplot`.

```
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=none},
extra x ticks={-3.14159, -1.5708, 1.5708, 3.14159},
extra x tick labels={${\makebox[0pt][r]{\tiny-}$\pi$}$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$},
```

I do not want the negative sign in the labels of the first two tick marks to displace `$\pi$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$`.

What is wrong with this code?  How do I make the typeset the minus sign in `\tiny` font?  Will the appropriate space be inserted between the minus sign and `$\pi$` and `$\frac{\pi}{2}$`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in,axis on top,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3.75,xmax=3.75,
    domain=-3.75:3.75,
    ymin=-0.25,ymax=2.25,
    restrict y to domain=-0.25:2.25,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=none},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={-3.14159, -1.5708, 1.5708, 3.14159},
    extra x tick labels={${\makebox[0pt][r]{\tiny-}$\pi$}$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$},
    extra y ticks={2},
    extra y tick style={y tick label style={anchor=south east}},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot [samples=501, domain=-3.5:3.5, blue] {1 + cos(deg(x))};
\addplot [samples=2, latex-latex, domain=-3.5:3.5] {1};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\makebox[0pt][r]{\tiny-}$\pi$` instead of `${\makebox[0pt][r]{\tiny-}$\pi$}$`

Comment: @salim bou  The `\makebox` command cannot be in `math in-line` mode?  Will the spacing between the minus sign and numbers be the same as what I would get with $-\pi$?

Comment: @Adelyn: This worked for me `\newcommand*{\AddIgnoredNegativeSign}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}#1}` and invoke this as `$\AddIgnoredNegativeSign{\pi}$`,  `$\AddIgnoredNegativeSign{\frac{\pi}{2}}$`. Also I think the use of `\tiny` is not a good idea, but that is just my opinion. On another note, I think the use of "minus" is incorrect, "minus" is a binary operator. In this case it is a "negative" sign.

Comment: @Peter Grill   I guess that you are telling me that the "negative" sign has a different spacing than the binary operation of subtraction.  May you describe the distinction for me?

Comment: @Adelyn: It just a matter of wording: "minus" means subtraction. There is no subtraction going on in "-5", thus this is "negative 5". However, "5-3" is "5 minus 3" _not_ "5 negative 3". And yes, you are correct in that as far as LaTeX goes the spacing between a unary negative sign and a binary minus is different. Also, the `-` should definitely be typeset in math mode.

Comment: @Peter Grill  Does `TikZ` render the code `$-5$` and the code `$-$5` identically?

Comment: @Adelyn: I think that would depend on if the math font was the same as the text font. Otherwise there will be a difference. The spacing should be the same if the two fonts are identical. BTW, its TeX that is rendering it, and not related to TiKZ.

Comment: @Peter Grill  I appreciate the comment that `TeX` is rendering the typesetting of the tick marks.  This tells me that `\makebox{$\scriptsize{-\pi}$}` and
`\makebox[0pt][r]{$\scriptsize-$}$\scriptsize{\pi}$` are typeset identically.

Comment: No `$\scriptsize{` is an error you can not have size change commands inside math mode.

Comment: @David Carlisle  `WinEdt` compiles code containing the commands `\makebox{$\scriptsize{-\pi}$}` and `\makebox[0pt][r]{$\scriptsize-$}$\scriptsize{\pi}`$ in in-line math mode, but it ignores the `scriptsize` command.   As you said, the font is not changed.  The code is compiled, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a math mode `-`. Size changes must be outside math mode, but you do not need a size change here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in,axis on top,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3.75,xmax=3.75,
    domain=-3.75:3.75,
    ymin=-0.25,ymax=2.25,
    restrict y to domain=-0.25:2.25,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=none},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={-3.14159, -1.5708, 1.5708, 3.14159},
    extra x tick labels={$\llap{$-$}\pi$, $\llap{$-$}\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$},
    extra y ticks={2},
    extra y tick style={y tick label style={anchor=south east}},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot [samples=501, domain=-3.5:3.5, blue] {1 + cos(deg(x))};
\addplot [samples=2, latex-latex, domain=-3.5:3.5] {1};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess `\llap` is part of the `positioning` package.  What is the web site containing the manual for this package?

Comment: @Adelyn `\llap` is from plain tex and the latex format it's just `\hbox to 0pt{\hss#1}` so the same as `\makebox[l][0pt]`